# Laravel Schedule Command Not Working In EC2 with Sail

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-sail, laravel-scheduler

I have the laravel app running with Sail in EC2 Ubuntu AWS server.

I already have the command `emails:send-weekly` that I have tested with both `php artisan emails:send-weekly` and `./vendor/bin/sail emails:send-weekly` working as expected which is sending emails to all users in my app.

But when I add laravel schedule in `app/Console/Kernel.php`:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('emails:send-weekly')->weeklyOn(3, '13:00')->timezone('Asia/Jakarta');
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

The schedule is not working, I can see that the schedule list next due is counting down, but after the count down is over, I have not receive any email.

I have tried `php artisan schedule:list` and `./vendor/bin/sail schedule:list`, both of them returning:

40 23 * * 3  php artisan emails:send-weekly . Next Due: 6 days from now.

Please tell me how to fix this? is there anything I need to set up to enable the schedule?

Comment: please share your crontab details too. you will see the detail by running this command 'crontab -e'

Comment: thank you very much @salarzaidi ! turns out I forgot to set up my crontab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to set up my crontab. By opening crontab with 'crontab -e' and adding this code at the end of my crontab, the scheduler works as expected:

```
40 23 * * 3 cd laravel && php artisan emails:send-weekly >> /dev/null 2>&1
```